# JBPM 7.44 Task with correct owner returns "no current match"

Tags: jbpm

I have a process with a serial and a parallel version of what it does for both groups and individuals.  I am changing the processes to use a reusable subprocess to maintain one version used in four places as opposed to four versions.  The parallel individual version of what is being done works, but the serial individual version is returning

```
ERROR [org.jbpm.process.instance.timer.TimerManager] (EJB default - 1) Error when executing timer job: org.jbpm.workflow.instance.WorkflowRuntimeException: [AMS_Workflow:20,270 - Serial Individual Task:60] -- [AMS.SendMessagesWorkflow:20,271 - Update Workflow for Task:12] -- User '[UserImpl:'0BD0194B-0000-4AED-9161-43D030686D7E']' was unable to execute operation 'Start' on task id 20336 due to a no 'current status' match
```

The user id above (0BD0194B-0000-4AED-9161-43D030686D7E) is the actualOwnerId of the task (20336) according to the task table.  What could be causing the no current status match (given it is Reserved for the correct user) in the following code?

```
// Start thisTask
org.jbpm.services.api.UserTaskService taskService = (org.jbpm.services.api.UserTaskService) serviceRegistry.service(org.jbpm.services.api.service.ServiceRegistry.USER_TASK_SERVICE);
taskService.setName(pamTaskId, stage.getName() + " :: " + thisTask.getName());
taskService.setDescription(pamTaskId,
    ( "Individual thisTask {OnFirstCompletion=" + amsTask.getCompleteOnFirstCompletion() + 
       <irrelevant details> 
    + "}"));
System.out.println("about to start task id=" + pamTaskId + " owner=" + thisTask.getOwner());
taskService.start(pamTaskId, thisTask.getOwner());  // removed argument from call: userTaskInst.getDeploymentId(),
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there was a disconnect between the way the Task was seen at the process level and at the sub-process level and in the DB.  The database was correctly in "Reserved" state but when I did an call to get the internal state it was "Exited"

```
org.jbpm.services.api.UserTaskService taskService = (org.jbpm.services.api.UserTaskService) serviceRegistry.service(org.jbpm.services.api.service.ServiceRegistry.USER_TASK_SERVICE);
org.kie.api.task.model.Task internalTask = taskService.getTask(taskId);
System.out.println("internal task has status=" + internalTask.getTaskData().getStatus().toString());
```

I ended up passing in a model of my task from the process to the subprocess and navigating the API's to get a task with an state of Reserved (and matched the DB)

Answer (score 0):

What is the "current status" of the task? It should be in "Reserved" state to call Start.

Comment: Thanks, it was.  I will post the answer.

Comment: You lead him to the answer (which you could have done with a comment instead) but didn't provide an answer in the posting. So this doesn't work as an answer unless you provide more information.

Nice try though.